# My batch code skips past if statements

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

**NOTE:** This is not a duplicate because the other questions I found are not the same goal as mine and is a different `if statement`.

I wanted to make a batch file that can remember your name, even after being closed. It saves the name in a text file and then reads from it. My question is it skips past my first `if statement`. Why does it do this? When I type `y` it goes to `:no`. I think this is because right after the `if statement` is the `:no` part, but what am I doing wrong? If you don't understand this, just copy this code and paste in notepad and then save as `ANYTHING.bat` and run it, and you'll see what I mean.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
@echo off
title The logger
echo NAME> log1.txt
set /p name=<log1.txt

:start
cls
echo Your name is %name%, right? (Y/N)
set /p input=
if %input%=="Y" goto yes
if %input%=="y" goto yes
if %input%=="N" goto no
if %input%=="n" goto no

:no
echo Oh... then what is it?
set /p name=
echo OK! Thanks, %name%
echo %name%>log1.txt
pause
goto start

:yes
echo hahahaha i knew it
echo Would you like to change it? (Y/N)
set /p input=

if %input%=="Y" goto namechange
if %input%=="y" goto namechange
if %input%=="N" (
    echo Ok.
    pause
    goto start
)
if %input%=="n" (
    echo Ok.
    pause
    goto start
)
goto start

:namechange
echo What should it be?
set /p name=
echo %name%>log1.txt
echo Thanks, %name%
pause
goto start
```

Comment: Your note is nonsense and only an excuse for not having researched properly nor having read `help if`

Answer (score 0):

`IF` syntax is `if string1 operator string2 action`

If `string1` or `string2` is "quoted" (which allows a string to contain spaces) then **BOTH** strings must be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some very small changes to your code that make it run perfectly as well as having a more accurate guess for the first name.

```
@echo off
title The logger
echo %username%> log1.txt
set /p name=<log1.txt
set remove=0123456789
set string=%name%
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=%remove%" %%a in ("%string%") do (
echo %%a%%b > log1.txt
)
set /p name=<log1.txt


:start
cls
echo Your name is %name%, right? (Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
if "%input%"=="Y" goto yes
if "%input%"=="y" goto yes
if "%input%"=="N" goto no
if "%input%"=="n" goto no

:no
echo Oh... then what is it?
set /p name=
echo OK! Thanks, %name%
echo %name%>log1.txt
pause
goto start

:yes
echo hahahaha i knew it
echo Would you like to change it? (Y/N)
set /p input=

if "%input%"=="Y" goto namechange
if "%input%"=="y" goto namechange
if "%input%"=="N" (
    echo Ok.
    pause
    goto start
)
if "%input%"=="n" (
    echo Ok.
    pause
    goto start
)
goto start

:namechange
echo What should it be?
set /p name=
echo %name%>log1.txt
echo Thanks, %name%
pause
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is take away the "Quotation marks" from around the Y & N.